# I compile and then run this bit of code in java.exe and i receive an error

Tags: java, class, methods

I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this code. Eclipse tells me main method isn't declared. and when I run it in java.exe it tells me "could not find or load main class discount.java" I've spent the last half hour looking for a solution but can't seem to figure it out.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Discount
    {
      public static void main (String[] args) 
      {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        int price;

        System.out.println("Enter the Price:");
        price = scan.nextInt();


        System.out.println( price / 4 * 3  );
      }
    }
```

The commands I'm using and error I'm getting:

```
> CD C:\Programing\Misc
> set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin
> javac discount.java
> java discount.java
Error: Could not find out or load main class java.discount
```

Comment: To start of, Class name should be CAPITALIZED ..Discount

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and say you didn't name the file `discount.java`

Comment: I have captilized the Class name and named the file discount.java. they are both correct. xD

Comment: @dada11dada22 i have run this code in Eclipse and it compiles

Comment: if you changed the class name then you have to change the filename to match

Comment: Your class name should match the filename exactly. Seeing that you changed it here, did you change the filename too?

Comment: CD C:\Programing\Misc |
set path=%path%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin |
javac discount.java |
java discount.java |
Error: Could not find out or load main class java.discount | Cant seem to edit this into the question area

Comment: The command to run should be `java Discount` without the `.java` at the end. `javac ClassName.java` compiles the _file_ `ClassName.java` (which must contain the source for the class `ClassName`); `java ClassName` runs the `main` method in the _class_ `ClassName` which will be in the bytecode file `ClassName.class` created by `javac`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `java discount.java`? That's likely the issue.

Try these two lines:

`javac discount.java
java discount`

That should run your main method (assuming that you've correctly named the file discount.java).

--

**EDIT**: After seeing your comment about changing the class name, you'll want to rename the file to Discount.java. Then run `javac Discount.java` and `java Discount`

Comment: Now that his classname is `Discount` the filename should also be `Discount.java`

Comment: okay yes, i just realized i was running java discount.java 
Thank you . XD

Answer (score 0):

The filename has to match the classname exactly, so put this in the file `Discount.java` (`discount.java` won't work).

Then, from my command-line:

```
% javac Discount.java
% java Discount 
Enter the Price:
^C
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this file hierarchy and how to compile java on command line
[image]

Comment: I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: @iamnotmaynard well maybe not but it could be ;)